# A powerful vice. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Fine, precise,
>
> a powerful vice.
>
> I draw up blood, thin crimson penned;
>
> Yet with never a wound can I contend.
>
> Under careful conditions am I used,
>
> although on occasion I've been abused.
>
> Many an ache have I helped ease;
>
> I have even aided the diseased.
>
> I have helped many people escape;
>
> yet I imbue no movement.

Who am I?

---

*This is my first time on the Puzzling Stack Exchange. Feel free to give comments or criticisms, I love to hear it.*

*This is also my first riddle, and I'm worried it may be pretty easy. A line by line breakdown on how your answer fits is welcome!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a little on-the-nose, but is it

> a needle? (i.e., a syringe)

Fine, precise,

> needles are marked for measurement, usually fine measurement

a powerful vice.

> they can contain powerful drugs, the use of which is known as a "vice"

I draw up blood, thin crimson penned;

> well, drawing up blood is one thing that needles are known to do

Yet with never a wound can I contend.

> a needle will ... probably? ... not release as much blood as an open wound would

Under careful conditions am I used,

> doctors and nurses try to be careful when using needles

although on occasion I've been abused.

> as mentioned above, needles can be used to inject drugs. in some cases this is called "drug abuse"

Many an ache have I helped ease;

> opioid narcotics (the legal kind and the illegal kind), for one example, are administered with needles

I have even aided the diseased.

> as noted above, needles can be used to inject substances for medicinal purposes

I have helped many people escape;

> "escape" is being used in the mental/emotional sense here - drugs administered with needles can provide an escape from reality

yet I imbue no movement.

> the needle itself does not propel anyone forward (or in any other direction), per se

*I really feel like I'm missing something about this one*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! +1 for prompt and good answer!